# Is it bad practice to add custom objects to json data structure?

Tags: json, swift

if I have a JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    events: {
        event1: {
            uid: "user1"
        }
    }
    users: {
        user1: {
            name: "foo"
        }
    }
}
```

I'll use Swift here to model the JSON in code. A user structure will look like so:

```
struct User {
    let name: String
}
```

and if I was to model an event the same way as in the structure, it would look like:

```
struct Event {
    let uid: String
}
```

Eventually, say I want to access the information about the user whose ID (`uid`) appears in the event. Would it be appropriate to save a `User` object directly in `Event`? I.e:

```
struct Event {
    let uid: String
    let user: User
}
```

I can use `uid` to know from where to load the `User` object, and have the information about the user from the initialization of `Event`. Is it okay to have a structure in the program that contains attributes which differ from the raw JSON? If not, when should the `User` object be loaded in this case? Thanks.

Comment: JSON is just a data interchange format. It says nothing about how your application works.

Answer (score 0):

JSON in swift can be parsed as dictionary or array, depends on its layout. For your structs, they are just something to hold data from your JSON. If you feel comfortable to have attribute name different than the JSON keys, that's fine. The button line is you have to parse the JSON and create struct base of the value you retrieved from dictionary or array. The attributes name in the struct does not matter in this process.

Comment: How complex can the struct get, thought? Will it become difficult to parse the JSON?

Comment: @ArchieGertsman You can have a struct inside a struct if you want, that all depends on your preference. For JSON parsing no that't not difficult. All you need to do is to go level by level. And in this process, you can create structs level by level too.